# Can a minaret have auxiliary functionality, such as also being a clock tower or lighthouse?

Tags: masjid

On my travels, I'm yet to see a [minaret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minaret) be used for auxiliary purposes.  This is what they often look like:

[image: Minaret of the Hassan II Mosque, Casablanca, Morocco]

This is the [Hassan II Mosque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hassan_II_Mosque) in Casablanca, Morocco.  It would be possible to add a clockface to the minaret, or turn it into a lighthouse (the Hassan II Mosque is on the beach), in order to give it additional functionality.  However, I have never seen this happen in practice.

**Question**: Can a minaret have auxiliary functionality, such as also being a clock tower or lighthouse?

Here I use "can" as shorthand for "is it Islamically permissible" (I'm not asking "is it physically possible").